# Query String Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Looking to create a short url tool and want to be able to go to;

`www.website.co.uk/j2ExICY`

and actually load

`www.website.co.yk/?u=j2ExICY` however keeping the url as `www.website.co.uk/j2ExICY` the whole time.

Do you know how to control this through the .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in root/htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect

```
 /foo
```

to

```
/?u=foo
```